# How is a gable vent attached to vinyl siding?

Tags: vinyl-siding, insect

Apparently this gable vent wasn't installed correctly as there is a horde of wasps that has moved in.  My plan had been to douse them with waspicide, remove the vent, and then seal the hole, but I'd rather not be standing there for a long time figuring out the "remove the vent" step.

Online, it seems like a lot of these are installed with nails from the outside, but there aren't any visible, so it's got to be something more clever.  Does it just snap on and off?  Do I have to climb inside my attic and unscrew something from the inside?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: look for screws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, it is a typical install for vinyl siding.

This could be installed in 2 different ways. Either way the vent or portion of the vent is installed before the siding goes on.

First way, a base plate or ring that will hold the grille/vent is nailed in place first. It defines the shape of the vent, and provides the means to hold the finished part that shows in place. This allows for easy cutting and installing the siding with the proper expansion gaps around the base of the vent.

The second way, it goes on as a one piece unit, with a nail flange just like the first one, that gets hidden by the siding, but this one will need to have the siding place into the groove around the perimeter, making it a bit more difficult to install.

Comment: Thanks!  If it is the first way, how does the vent then attach to the base plate?

Comment: They often just snap on.

Comment: It simply snaps in place over the base ring. This is the most likely way it is installed. Just to let you know, vinyl needs room to expand, do not do something to "lock it in place", unless it has room at the ends....

Comment: Will silicone caulk have enough "give" that I can seal any gaps, but still let the siding expand?

Comment: When you get the cover off if that is the way it is set up, and IF the siding was nailed properly You should be able to shift the siding left and right by placing the palms of your hands on the siding to allow the friction to move the siding. If you an do so, center the siding the best you can in its position, so when you seal it in the center, the ends will still expand and contract with seasonal changes. On longer lengths of siding, expect it to shrink and grow as much as 3/4".... 3/8" at each end. Silicone is ok, it can be really messy. Use the right size backer rod to fill most of the void